# Passing variable via href using PHP

Tags: php, html

```
<a href= \"edit_form.php?id = $row[ID]\">Edit</a>
```

How can I pass variable in href? Is my code syntax correct? I want to pass the variable to another PHP file.

Can someone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

You're almost there.  Spaces are not allowed in urls.. so you need to remove those. Not to mention as this html is not in an echo, you need to enclose the `$row` variable in php syntax:

```
<a href="edit_form.php?id=<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>">Edit</a>
```

Comment: you don't need to escape the double quotes of the `href` since it's not an `echo`.

Comment: @tradyblix A vote down for that?  You could have easily alerted and I would have fixed it, as I have now.

Comment: I only commented but didn't downvote, in fact I was just voting up when you fixed it. :)

Comment: @tradyblix Retracted then; sorry for any misunderstanding. :)

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way to pass values via url (not the safest way tho) -

```
<a href="edit_form.php?id=<?php echo $row[id] ;?> " >Edit</a>
```

OR

```
echo '<a href="edit_form.php?id='. $row[id] .'" >Edit</a>';
```

Whatever suits your scripting...

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
echo '<a href="edit_form.php?id='. $row[id] .'" >Edit</a>';
```

if you want to send the values through the anchor